# How can I expose event creation fields on Drupal 8 front end without CiviCRM Entity?

Tags: civievent, drupal-8

A key feature and service of our Drupal 8 site (in development) is to allow users to create their own events. I want to expose some of the event creation fields to them on the front end. Is there a way to do this in Drupal 8?

When I research, I see solutions that involve CiviCRM Entity and Webforms, but Entity does not appear to have a stable Drupal 8 release (the latest is 8.x-3.x-dev, updated on August 14th).

If the event creation fields were available when creating a profile, I would do it that way. Since I don't have sufficient programming experience to properly build an extension, my backup is to style the admin interface and CiviEvent creation form to look as much like our public-facing site as possible, but that's a last resort.

I apologize if this question has been answered already, and I missed other proposed solutions. Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an extension isn't on the table, then I think that CiviCRM Entity is the way to go, despite the lack of a stable release.

For what it's worth, it's not terribly uncommon to have sites in production with modules that don't have stable releases.  It means more testing ensuring it works for your use case - but that testing also helps build toward the common solution that in a few months will be the standard way of doing what you're describing.

You may also research the [Form Processor extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/form-processor) - but this relies on having a Drupal module like CiviMRF, which doesn't have a D8 version.

Finally - I would chat with the folks behind both of these solutions.  In particular, https://chat.civicrm.org has a "CiviCRM Entity" channel where you can talk with the authors.  They may also be open to a sponsorship to prioritize the features you need.

Comment: Jon G, thank you. This is reassuring information. I tried it with the dev release, and it seems to work fine so far (and the good news is that I don't need particularly unique features -- I just want to avoid preventable bugginess). I think I will work with this, and do as you noted: contribute to the improvement of the module by seeing what comes up and communicating with the developers about it.